# Javascript not accepting Date or String as parameters using Razor and MVVM

Tags: c#, javascript, html, razor, mvvm

I have a problem with my JavaScript method not firing or giving incorrect values.

Javascript:

```
function JSMethod(UserID, medalDate, medalCategory{
    //Do things.
};
```

HTML:

```
//MediaList consists of: int UserID, DateTime DateEarned, string Reason
@foreach (var medal in @Model.medalList)
{
    <a onclick="JSMethod(@medal.UserID, @medal.DateEarned.ToShortDateString(), @medal.Reason.ToString())" click here</a> 
}
```

The JavaScript method does not seem to take the `@model.Reason` as a parameter, is there a problem with passing in strings to Javascript functions?

When the date (`@medal.DateEarned`) is passed in it either ignores it or passes it in as `ToString('DD/MM/YYYY')` and it ends up dividing, for example, 12/03/2014 resulting in a passed in parameter of 0.00198...

Is there anyway of getting my JavaScript function to accept my datetime and string as parameters?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: No problem with passing strings in javascript. What is your function doing with the passed in values?

Comment: You have a typo in your JS function, you are missing the parenthesis that closes the argument list. Is that a copy&paste from your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When mixing Razor and JavaScript, you have to remember the syntax for both languages: in this case, you need to use quotes in the JavaScript around your Razor-injected values:

```
<a onclick="JSMethod(@medal.UserID, '@medal.DateEarned.ToShortDateString()', '@medal.Reason.ToString()')" click here</a>
```

Note the tick marks around the date and reason strings. If UserID is not numeric, it needs ticks as well.

Comment: After adding ticks I'm able to get the Date in JavaScript function. Is it a good practise to put all the values inside ticks? @JoelCochran

Comment: Not every value - it depends on the types the JS function expects.